# Как сделать, чтобы php mailer отправлял на почту клиента файл, лежащий на хостинге?

Tags: php, sendmail, phpmailer

Одновременно надо отправить заявку на почту клиента, и отправить вложение на почту, указанную в заявке.

Текущий код:

```
<?php </br>
require_once('phpmailer/PHPMailerAutoload.php');</br>
$mail = new PHPMailer;</br>
$mail->CharSet = 'utf-8';</br>
$email = trim($_POST["email"]);<br>
$phone = trim($_POST["phone"]);<br>
//$mail->SMTPDebug = 3; // Enable verbose debug output<br>
$mail->isSMTP(); // Set mailer to use SMTP<br>
$mail->Host = 'smtp.mail.ru'; // Specify main and backup SMTP servers<br>
$mail->SMTPAuth = true; // Enable SMTP authentication<br>
$mail->Username = 'mail@mail.ru'; // Ваш логин от почты с которой будут отправляться письма <br>
$mail->Password = 'password'; // Ваш пароль от почты с которой будут отправляться письма<br>
$mail->SMTPSecure = 'ssl'; // Enable TLS encryption, `ssl` also accepted<br>
$mail->Port = 465; // TCP port to connect to / этот порт может отличаться у других провайдеров<br>
$mail->setFrom('mail@mail.ru'); // от кого будет уходить письмо?<br>
$mail->addAddress('ellen@example.com'); // Кому будет уходить письмо<br>
//$mail->addAddress('ellen@example.com'); // Name is optional<br>
//$mail->addReplyTo('info@example.com', 'Information');<br>
//$mail->addCC('cc@example.com');<br>
//$mail->addBCC('bcc@example.com');<br>
//$mail->addAttachment('/var/tmp/file.tar.gz'); // Add attachments<br>
//$mail->addAttachment('/tmp/image.jpg', 'price.jpg'); // Optional name
$mail->isHTML(true); // Set email format to HTML<br>
$mail->Subject = 'Сообщение с сайта ';<br>
$mail->Body = ' Телефон :' .$phone. '<br>Почта: ' .$email;<br>
$mail->AltBody = '';<br>
?>
```

Этот код просто отправляет заявку. А как его дописать, чтобы клиенту прилетал файл с прайсом с хостинга?

Answer (score 0):

```
$mail->addAttachment('/var/tmp/file.tar.gz');
```

можно так, но нужно указать свой файл с путем.

Comment: и этот файл отправиться на email который был взят из формы?

Comment: надо пробовать. Попробуйте на свой мейл отправить.

Comment: я знаю, как отправлять файлы на свой мейл. мне нужно с моего хостинга на мейл клиенту отправлять автоматически после того как клиент заявку оставляет

Comment: попробуйте сделать как я написал и отправить заявку со своим мейлом. Увидите придет файл или нет.

Answer (score 0):

Если в Вашей форме есть элемент `<input type="file">` с именем , скажем, `uploaded_file`, то

```
if (isset($_FILES['uploaded_file']) &&
    $_FILES['uploaded_file']['error'] == UPLOAD_ERR_OK) {
    $mail->AddAttachment($_FILES['uploaded_file']['tmp_name'],
                     $_FILES['uploaded_file']['name']);
}
```

Также важно, чтобы у формы был атрибут `enctype="multipart/form-data"`.